# Delete files using shell script with some additional parameters ( windows )

Tags: image, shell, dataset

I have a dataset contains ( .csv files and images ) but I have some images are not annotated, that means the number of images < number of .csv files.

I have placed all images to the folder that contains the .csv files.
I would like to know if is it possible to delete additional images ( images without annotations, I mean images without a correspondent .csv files ) with a shell script or command line?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by this command:

> for f in *.jpg; do [[ -f ${f%.*}.csv ]] || echo "$f"; done

**The Source of the solution:**

[linux- Script to compare and delete the files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331554/script-to-compare-and-delete-the-files-based-on-name-and-extension-type)